# Is it efficient to Remove items from array OR Create new array for remaining items ( Javascript )

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an pendingOrders array, I need to put a logic for checking Order status in loop.

I want to understand whether it be efficient to remove completed items from original array or  would it be efficient to create new array for remaining orders.

It may not be great savings but still It would be nice to understand this.

```
var pendingOrders = [ ];
pendingOrders[0] = {OrderId: 1};
pendingOrders[1] = {OrderId: 2};
pendingOrders[2] = {OrderId: 3};


//Call CheckOrderStatus function
CheckOrderStatus(pendingOrders );

CheckOrderStatus(pendingOrders )
{

//Some logic to find completed orders
//Suppose OrderId : 1 is completed


//Now which one of following will be efficient ?

//Approach 1 - remove Completed Orders from original array pendingOrders using function removeByAttribute ( given below) 

             //Remove object by value
             removeByAttribute (pendingOrders, 'OrderId', 1);  

             //again call this after 10 seconds
             CheckOrderStatus(pendingOrders);

//OR 

//Approach 2 - instead of removing simply create new array 

              //Simply create new array for remaining orders
              var stillPendingOrders = [ ];   
              stillPendingOrders [1] = {OrderId: 2};
              stillPendingOrders [2] = {OrderId: 3};


               //again call this after 10 seconds
               CheckOrderStatus(stillPendingOrders );
}



   /*Utility Function: Removes an Object Item from an array -
    *
    * @param arr - Array
    * @param attr - Attribute name
    * @param value - Attribute value
    *
    * @returns  arr - modified array
    */
    var removeByAttribute = function(arr, attr, value){
        var i = arr.length;
        while(i--){
            if(arr[i] && arr[i].hasOwnProperty(attr) && (arguments.length > 2 && arr[i][attr] === value )){
                arr.splice(i,1);
            }
        }
        return arr;
    }
```

Comment: The answer to nearly all JavaScript performance questions is ***it depends***. Some things are more efficient on some engines and less efficient on others. The only way to know is to test it (using http://jsperf.com or similar) on your target engines. Separately, "efficient" is a vague term -- efficient in what sense? Speed? Memory consumption/memory churn?

Comment: I am mainly concerned more about Speed  and little about memory consumption ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would guess creating an array is faster in your scenario. The removeAttribute() function should be slower since you have a while loop and then you call Array.splice() (which in the mozilla implementation has 200+ lines of code). Array splice does not only manipulate the existing array, but also returns a new array containing the deleted elements.

However, I agree with T.J Crowder comment that the only correct approach is to measure the efficiency using profilers. To prove my assumptions are right, here is a quick jsperf.com test:

http://jsperf.com/stackoverflow-remove-vs-create

based on the test above the removeByAttribute() scenario is slower 79% on my box in chrome and safari than the create array approach (using your test data). However in firefox it is the opposite. I am not sure if this is a realistic scenario, and you should test with bigger data-sets.

If you want to test this stuff in your own environment/setup (which i would recommend), you can use the same benchmarking library used by jsperf:

http://benchmarkjs.com/

To monitor memory consumption you can use chrome developer tools.

Comment: Thanks for your input, I was having similar thoughts.